# Very low internet speed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, hp, download-speed

I have tried many solutions on online forums for this, but none helped. 
Under the same WiFi network, my mobile phone and other laptops running windows or Ubuntu get a speed of around 4mbps(downloading) while my laptop (HP Pavilion P001-tx) gets around 200kbps.

The same file was used for downloading so no issue of server or so.

Few Details,

```
Description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 14:2d:27:dc:93:57
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:b5500000-b5507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: 6c:c2:17:6f:05:f6
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff


flag
```

This came up when I ran the above command:

```
eno1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 6c:c2:17:6f:05:f6 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 --

lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 --

wlo1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 14:2d:27:dc:93:57 
inet addr:192.168.0.107 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 
inet6 addr: fe80::162d:27ff:fedc:9357/64 Scope:Link 
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 –
```

Running tracepath, I get,

```
1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
```

Comment: `ifconfig | grep -B3 MTU` is your `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit). Should be smaller for WiFi

Comment: This came up when I ran the above command: 
`eno1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:c2:17:6f:05:f6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
--lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
--wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:2d:27:dc:93:57  
          inet addr:192.168.0.107  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::162d:27ff:fedc:9357/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1`

Comment: Don't put output  in the comments. Rather, edit your post, and put the output there, with formatting. I'll do it for you this time, but you should change your behavior.

Comment: First time here, will remember this from now on!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the formatted results, your wifi (`wlo1`) MTU is too large, leading every packet to be fragmented. If you get your IP address via DHCP, the DHCP server should set your MTU (fix it there), or to do it manually,

You can find your correct MTU value via

```
tracepath -n 8.8.8.8
```

It's a function of WiFi, PPPoE, and whatever else is between you and the Internet.

If it turns out to be, say, 1432, change it locally by:

```
sudo ifconfig wlo1 down
sudo ifconfig wlo1 mtu 1432
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

Comment: How much shoud I change the MTU to? Its 1500, as shown in the edit above.

Comment: My other laptop has also 1500 MTU, which gets good speed.

Comment: Also set the wireless encryption, at the router, to WPA2-AES. Mixed modes (WPA/WPA2) and/or TKIP tend to have that effect in Broadcom chips with the Linux driver.

Comment: @MichaelBay: It's more like a public WiFi, so can't make changes there.

Comment: If so I'm afraid it has no solution because the solution is using the expert recommended settings at the router: WPA2-AES only. If you can't change the settings, move on, use another network.

Comment: @MichaelBay: That isn't a solution. Am i now just restricted to these networks only then?

Comment: That's exactly what I said: No solution (except adopting the recommended settings or using a different WiFi chip knowing that if the new hardware+driver combo allows such insecure settings that is NOT a good thing).

Comment: @MichaelBay: Okay, so I connected to my home network and it also works slow. It is infact WPA2-AES. So any other means? Maybe I have some settings or driver wrong? Anyway to check that?

Comment: When a Broadcom connects the driver is usually correct. You can check and confirm the general procedure here https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers